# How to call a private API from Monotouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, uitextview

My knowledge on `P/Invoke` within Monotouch is pretty dire and I'm wanting to call a private iOS API for a `UITextView` (specifically `setContentToHTMLString`) and I'm not sure about where to even start with this.

If anyone could tell me how this is done (or even where to begin!) that would be brilliant.

Just to note, this is for a personal project I'm doing, mostly to widen my knowledge. The chances of this app getting submitted to the app store are very slim, so it isn't subject to App Store regulations / the possiblity of Apple changing it.

*edit*

Is it just simply a case of using a `Selector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to to call it using a selector, like this:

```
Selector s = new Selector("myPrivateAPIMethodName");
MyObjectToCallTheMethodOn.PerformSelector(s, parameterOfTheObject, 0);
```

Of course, be really careful about this.. Apple doesn't tolerates private API calls on your app, so if you're planning on going to the AppStore with something like this against the API like you want, they'll reject your app.

Comment: PerformSelector only works for selectors without arguments, fwiw.  I'm hesitant to answer how you can do this tho, since apple has good reason why you shouldn't call private abi, even in some obfuscated way.

Comment: I'll be honest, this app definitely won't be going to the appstore. I think I've broken so many of Apple's HI rules that they'd have a field day finding reasons to reject my app! But fair enough on being hesitant on answering - whereas I won't be submitting this to the app store, putting the knowledge out there means it may encourage others to include the private APIs in their app.

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer because it technically answers the question (calling private APIs without arguments at least).

Comment: @Geoff: Private APIs can be very useful in debugging in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call a private .net method you can use reflection.

You can use the code below as an example:

```
            object oToInvoke;

        //Get the type of object
        Type t = typeof( oToInvoke );

        //Invoke 'PrivateMethodName'
        return t.InvokeMember( "PrivateMethodName",
                          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
                        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
                        , null
                        , oToInvoke
                        , null );
```

This would allow to to invoke a method which can have a return type. You just need to cast the return type of InvokeMember

Thats in the System.Reflection Namespace

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm wanting to call a private API for an native iOS object (Objective-C) so this didn't work. However, I didn't know how to call private .net methods either so this is very useful, thankyou!

Comment: Ah ok, no worries, I'm starting to learn iOS development so if perhaps ill come across it sometime :)